Dynamic Pages in next.js app router with static export
I am creating one application which needs to be hosted on aws s3 bucket and we want to deploy this one as static so we are using output: "export" in next.js config file now with this we want to create dynamic pages with client components but it is showing missed generateStaticParams function error, and we can not use this one as we dont know what url slug can come ahead of time, so is there any way to achieve this behavior in next.js
